# typing async iterators: error TS2347: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, iterator, iterable

I am trying to write a custom [asyncIterable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/esnext.asynciterable.d.ts#L14) to fetch some data in batches and loop through the batches. I am trying to do this to avoid timeouts in my worker. Following is my code:

```
import { SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric } from 'InterfaceDefinitionFile'

async getIterable(): Promise<
      AsyncIterable<SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric[]> // previously written as T
  > {
    const count = await getTotalCount()
    const batchesCount = Math.ceil(count / BATCH_SIZE)

    let i = 0
    const iterator = {
        async next(): Promise<IteratorResult<SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric[]>> {
            const data: SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric[] = await repository.findByCriteria<
              SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric
            >(searchCriteria, {
                limit: BATCH_SIZE,
                skip: i * BATCH_SIZE
            }) // this function needs generic and the error points to this line
            await Promise.all(
                data.map(datum=> {
                    // augment some data to each item
                    return this.asyncTask(datum)
                })
            )
            i++
            return {
                value: data,
                done: i === batchesCount
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            return iterator
        }
    }
}
```

And the function is called like follows:

```
const iterableDataBatches: AsyncIterable<
    SomeDataInterfaceNotGeneric[]
> = await getIterable() // function call
for await (const batchChunk of data) {
    batchChunk.forEach(async data => {
        // some operations
        await this.publishChanges()
    })
}
```

I get this error: 

`error TS2347: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`

I tried the solution on [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1634) post by declaring es6-promise explicitly which gives this error: 

`error TS2529: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'. Compiler reserves name 'Promise' in top level scope of a module containing async functions.`

Reference for [IteratorResult<T>](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts)

**UPDATE 1**
T is not generic type here but a definite type of the data. sorry for the confusion.

**UPDATE 2**

```
async findByCriteria<T>(
    searchCriteria: SelectorQuery | {},
    additionalQuery: AdditionalQueryInterface = {
        sort: {},
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0
    }
): Promise<T[]> {
    const [sort, skip, limit] = [
        additionalQuery.sort || {},
        additionalQuery.skip || 0,
        additionalQuery.limit || 0
    ]
    const db = await this.dbPromise
    return db
        .collection(this.collectionName)
        .find(searchCriteria)
        .sort(sort)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .toArray()
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in Symbol.asyncIterator - `iterotor`

Comment: What is `T` and where is it defined? Does this code belong to a generic class?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sorry for the typo. it is there because I am trying to anonymize my code to bare generic. not the cause of error prompt.

Comment: @OscarPaz T is not a generic type. sorry for the confusion. it is the type of my data. I updated the code.

Comment: Are you sure that repository.findByCriteria is generic? Can you post the method declaration?

Comment: @OscarPaz i updated it.

Comment: Umh, you are sure that method needs to be generic? It seems, to me, that it always returns the same type, at least, the only parameter that I see can influence it is `this.collectionName`. But if it depends on `this.collectionName`, which is external to the function, then in my opinion it doesn't make sense to have a generic method. Shouldn't it better be defined as `findByCriteria: Promise<any[]>`? Then you can cast the result to whichever you want

Comment: @OscarPaz it is from generic repository but it is then injected to corresponding repository by passing definitive repository data type. so it needs to be generic. also, i think using <any> disregards the whole purpose of using typing system. i dont think it is advisable to use any.

Comment: But, is the repository generic, then? `any`may be useful when you don't know what kind of data you are dealing with, like in your case.Generics are useful when there are type constraints (you want a a method to return an array of the same type as a parameter, or so). In your case, the generic type is only used once, in the return type of the function. In your case, your method returns `any`. Yes, you force the method declaration to say it's `T` but that does not make it true. You're making an implicit type assertion, while, if you return `any` you're making an explicit type assertion.

Comment: yes it is generic. it's class is injected and it is initialized in the constructor  of the class where this error is being thrown from.